# Screen orientation problem with TChart in "Delphi 10.3 Rio"

Tags: android, delphi, charts, teechart, delphi-10.3-rio

I started working with "Delphi 10.3 Rio" and i'm looking at what seems to be a bug related to the TChart object. In an FMX application for "Android 8" I have just created a window with a single object, the TChart (`Chart1.Align := TAlignLayout.Client`). In the `OnClick` event I put the following:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if Application.FormFactor.Orientations = [TScreenOrientation.Landscape] then
      Application.FormFactor.Orientations := [TScreenOrientation.Portrait]
   else
      Application.FormFactor.Orientations := [TScreenOrientation.Landscape];
end;
```

ERROR: After changing the "Portrait" screen to "Landscape" and then returning to "Portrait", the screen isn't redrawn correctly and the bottom half is empty and black (cropped). See attached image.

How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: How this issue relates to TChart control?

Comment: Only with this object, the TChart, does the problem occur. If you simulate what I have described with another visual object, such as TPanel, TRectangle, or another visual container, that error does not occur.

Comment: Bug confirmed at the public tracker [#2142](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=2142)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I hope Team Steema can make corrections.

Comment: For now, have you tried the ScaledLayout component?  Just put the TChart on top of that and have it scale to the form?  This would be something you can do which is a little "hacky" that might just work.